# can use foreign keys in my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

i have 2 tables ( users and feedbacks ) . in the  the 2nd table i have **user_id** as a foreign key and i'm trying to get the name of the user who made the feedback

in  **User.php** :

```
 public function feedbackuser()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Feedback');
    }
```

in the **Feedback.php** :

```
  public function usersfeed(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
```

[image: feedbacks table]
[image: users table]

i tried those to methodes in y view :

```
{{$feedbacks->yser_id->name}}
```

and

```
{{$feedback->user_id['name']}}
```

**NB : this was working but when i added the relationships in phpmyadmin it stopped**

i was using this code :

```
@foreach($users as $user)
            @if ($user->id == $feedback->user_id)
            {{$user->name}}

            @endif
            @endforeach
```

Comment: “Yes?” - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships  , https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to query the relationship first then you can access the relational data.

Here is a pseudo code example:

```
{{ $user->feedbackuser->name }}
```

or the inverse of:

```
{{ $feedback->usersfeed->user_id }}
```